# buttons appear on screen before SCNView

Tags: ios, scenekit

In storyboard, I have buttons attached to main view as siblings to SCNView(both buttons and SCNView are subviews of main view). At launch time, the buttons appear on screen before the SCNView does. This is quite unfortunate. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

//edit: added button programatically in viedDidLoad: as a subview of SCNView..Still the same problem.

[image]

SettingsButton and View appear before SceneView. This happens on iPhone 5,5c and lower and on iPads.(3 for sure, don't know for others)

Code for adding view programatically:

```
let uv = UIView(frame:myFrame)
uv.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor
sceneView.addSubview(uv)// scene view from storyboard
```

Thats it. How can iOS take 5-10s to load an app, but than rushes with adding views to the screen in an unpredictable order.. Couldn't it just take 0.2s more and present view properly? Really stupid problem

Comment: can you post some code or piece of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine if you check via debugger breakpoints or logging in `viewDidLoad`, you'll find that the `SCNView` instance is indeed in the view hierarchy immediately.

What you're seeing is that said view's SceneKit *content* does not appear immediately. Depending on what you're doing with SceneKit, it may take some time to load content and prepare for rendering, and during that time the rest of the view hierarchy remains visible. That delay is probably unavoidable — you might be able to minimize it by optimizing asset formats, reducing the amount of stuff in your scene, etc. So it sounds like the key issue here is getting your app launch experience to look the way you want while accounting for the delay.

A good way to do that might be to show a splash image of some sort until SceneKit is ready to display. You could put a `UIImageView` in your storyboard, set up to obscure everything with a splash screen (possibly the same launch image iOS displays before your app takes over), then hide that image view (with a fade out even?) when SceneKit starts rendering.

To find out when SceneKit starts rendering, make one of your objects the scene renderer delegate and implement [renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRendererDelegate/renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:).  That method gets called on every frame, so you can use it to catch when the first frame has been rendered (and then ignore it for subsequent frames).